# Does ARM instruction "svc" update x0 register value?

Tags: assembly, system-calls, arm64

I am referring to the following document:
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest
In page number 1957, description and operation for svc is described.
There was no mention on x0 being updated with the syscall return value.
But i could see in few other websites:

https://cit.dixie.edu/cs/2810/arm64-assembly.html

https://azeria-labs.com/writing-arm-shellcode/

that [x0] or [register 0] is updated with the return value.

So i would like to know whether x0 is getting updated and if so, how to calculate the returned value? because I couldn't find it in the pseudo code listed in the ARM document

Comment: The `svc` instruction on its own does not change `x0`.  But that's like saying that the `bl` instruction does not change `x0`.  What does change `x0` is the code in the kernel called by `svc`

Comment: @fuz thank you very much for the response. Can you give me some directions so that i can read up more on it? currently, when going through the disassembly of an executable, i could see the following :  439b44: d4000001  svc #0x0  and after few lines there is cbnz w0, 4213d8 and here the x0 is 0 (so w0 - lower 32 bits, are also 0). In another location, after svc, the value of x0 becomes 0x48b000. So i would like to learn more so that i could code the same.

Comment: The `svc` instruction performs a system call.  That's like a function call, but goes to the operating system.  What the system call does and what registers it affects is highly dependent on the operating system you are programming for.  I'm not sure what sort of directions you expect.  You'll have to read up on the system calls provided by the operating system you are programming for.

Comment: @fuz okay, i see. Thank you very much. I greatly appreciate your suggestions. I was kind of lost while trying to figure out how the x0 was getting updated. Now that i know its due to the code in the kernel called by svc, i will look it up. Once again, thank you very much Fuz. Meet again later

Comment: Search for "AArch64 calling convention", pretty sure that `svc` follows exactly same convention as 'generic' function.

Comment: @user3124812 Thank you very much. I will look it up. Thank you.